# Angular js autocomplete search with link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement auto complete search with link(after selecting it should jump to particular page). only i need to hide the data appearing below search box, it should only display when user start type like search functionality works.

there are tow screen shot below, 1st one is what i have done where data is by default populated, so i want this to be hidden and when i type the it should display like screen2 
[image]

[image: data is getting populated from database using json but i need to hide the content apearing after input box, it shoul only come when i type the relevant text]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS</title>

<style>
ul,li{margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="movieCtrl"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="film">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in movies | filter:film | orderBy:'film'" style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="{{ x.param }}">{{ x.film  | uppercase }}</a></li>
</ul>

</div>    

<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('movieCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("tmp.php")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.movies = response.movie;});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to your list to only be visible if the filter is not empty:

```
<ul ng-show="film">
  <li ng-repeat="x in movies | filter:film | orderBy:'film'" style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="{{ x.param }}">{{ x.film  | uppercase }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, that really worked for me. on a lighter note I would like to know your suggestion that the above code i have written, is that the right way for make auto-complete search using Angular Js?

Comment: Well, it's definitely the easiest and fastest way. And as long as you don't have to paginate those results, you're all good.

Answer (score 0):

You add a variable (initially false) and hide your list based on that. Then when you change your input change the variable to true.
here is what you can do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="film" ng-init="show=0" ng-change="show=1">
```

and

```
<ul ng-show="show=1">
```